# Locally deleted branch is not deleted on remote repository

Tags: git, github, repository, branch

I have removed a branch I have after merging it with the master. However, the locally deleted branch is not deleted on remote repo (on github).

On a suggestion in one answer here, I tried `git push remote :branch` that didn't seem to help. `--prune` option didn't seem to help either.  I think I can go ahead and delete the branch remotely as well, but I don't want to be checking it and tracking with every branch.

Any ideas?

Comment: This question has already an answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to use this...

```
git push remote --delete <branch-name>
```

Although `git push remote :branch` should have worked. The command says *push this branch without a local set, effectively deleting it*.

Are you sure the name of your remote is *remote*? Could it be *origin*? Use `git remote -v` to list your remotes.

Failing that, [you can delete branches using GitHub's UI](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-unused-branches/).

Comment: Are you replacing *branch* there with the name of the remote branch?

Comment: Yep, sure. But didn't work.